# Geoserver commercial license

Tags: geoserver, license

Do you know that is possible to buy commercial license on Geoserver? I know that is under GPL 2.0 license and any changes have to be distributed also under this license. I would like to use Geoserver for commercial project.

Comment: This [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/jgarnett/understanding-open-source-78550455) helps understand the licenses and their interactions (geoserver + geotools + ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no possibility to purchase a licence and the project steering committee have no plans to dual licence GeoServer as there would be no benefit to us to do so.

Why do you need a commercial licence? If you want [support and maintenance](http://geoserver.org/support/) there are several companies around the world that can provide that service. If you just need to [extend GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/policies/gsip.html) please consider making an open contribution so that it is integrated into the code base for future releases.